# How do I prevent the enter key from triggering focusout, when handling both focusout and keydown?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am handling two events, both `focusout` and `keydown`, in a `$(elementID).on()` event-handler.

Calling `$(elementID).off("focusout keydown");` as the last line within the `.on()` event-handler seems to be *partially* working  --  `focusout` is working correctly, but `keydown` is firing **twice**.

---

*Edit:   With `@Barmar`'s findings, `keydown` is first triggering `focusout` and **then** `keydown`. This is happening in Firefox 22, but apparently not in Chrome 29.*

---

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type = "text" id = "textField" />
<input type = "button" onclick = "setFocus();" value = "click here" />

<ol>
      <li>Type some text into the textfield.</li>
      <li>Click the button.</li>
      <li>
            Click out of the textfield, or
            <br />
            <i>press enter for some weird behavior.</i>
      </li>
</ol>
```

...here is the javascript / jQuery:

```
 function setFocus() {
       $("#textField").focus();
       $("#textField").select();

       var count = 1;
       $("#textField").on("focusout keydown", function(e) {

              // if clicked away, or the enter key is pressed:
              if (e.type == "focusout" || e.keyCode == 13) {
                     alert(e.type + ": " + count++);
              }

              // this doesn't seem to be working correctly:
              $("#textField").off("focusout keydown");
       });
 }
```

...and here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icampbell2/yaFeF/)**.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 29, I get one alert.

Comment: @Barmar -- Wow, interesting... it alerts twice when enter is pressed in Firefox 22.

Comment: I changed it to `alert(e.type+count++)`, and in FF this shows that it's firing a `focusout` event when you press Enter.

Comment: Aha, thanks @Barmar! That seems to be the problem, but why is this happening?

Comment: Because when you press Enter, it goes to the next field, which means the focus is lost. But since it depends on the browser, one of them is probably wrong, or maybe the spec is ambiguous.

Comment: @Barmar -- sounds about right. Unfortunately `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()`, and `stopImmediatePropagation()` don't seem to be working..

Comment: Yeah, I tried preventDefault as well. Not sure what to recommend.

Comment: @Barmar -- I'm going to edit my question based on your findings.

Comment: @Ian Campbell have u tried my answer ????

Comment: @Sathya -- I've been busy, but have now tried it and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what i can deduce, that when you press enter **keydown** event is triggered alert for keydown opens and then **focusout** is triggered coz of enter default functionality then alert for focusout. So what you have to do is **unbind** the **focusout** if enter is pressed

```
    $("#textField").on("focusout keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.type == "focusout" || e.keyCode == 13) {
           if(e.keyCode == 13){
             $(this).unbind('focusout');
           }
        alert(e.type + ": " + count++);
        }
    $("#textField").off("focusout keydown");
    });
```

Here is the edited [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyaraj888/vt9YT/)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event binding instead of `on` ? then you wouldnt have to unbind at the end.

```
  $("#textField").one("focusout keydown", function(e) {

          // if clicked away, or the enter key is pressed:
          if (e.type == "focusout" || e.keyCode == 13) {
                 alert(count++);
          }
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yaFeF/12/

Comment: Thanks for the information @mkoryak, this is useful, however `keydown` is still firing twice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a nasty hack:

```
function setFocus() {
    $("#textField").focus();
    $("#textField").select();

    var count = 1;

    // when clicking away:
    $("#textField").on("focusout keydown", function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

        // if the key is NOT the enter or tab keys, which also trigger focusout:
        if (code !== 13 && code !== 9) {
            alert(e.type + ": " + count++);
        }

        $("#textField").off("focusout keydown");
    });

    // when hitting enter, or tabbing away:
    $("#textField").on("keydown", function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

        // if the key pressed is the enter or tab key:
        if (code === 13 || code === 9) {
            alert(e.type + ": " + count++);
        }

        $("#textField").off("keydown");
    });
}
```

...and the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icampbell2/HCjHr/).

---

I **don't** consider this a viable solution though, because this leads to unnecessary code duplication and is difficult to understand.

It seems as if `focusout` and `keydown` are inseparable... So handling both simultaneously and checking that `code !== 13` first, *then* handling only `keydown` and checking that `code === 13` will separate the events.

However, *now* the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key has to be handled too, **ack**! So, I have congruently included checks for `code !== 9` and `code === 9` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('Selector')
.on('keydown',function(e){
    if (13 == e.which) {
       // do somthing who lead 'focusout' like $('Somthing-else').click()
        $(this).unbind('focusout');
    }
})
.on('focusout', function(e){
    $('Somthing-else').click()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you have inline event.. `setFocus();` that was called when button is clicked.
remove inline event and change your script to this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var count= 1;
    $("#textField").on("focusout keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.type == "focusout" || e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert(count++);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: He wants you to have to click on the button to enable the other event handlers.

Comment: he wants? oh! sorry i dont see exactly that he wants to set that event on the button.. i see that his problem is some weird events that he wants to avoid

Comment: Read the instructions in the text, it says to type some text, then click on the button, then press Enter to see the problem. Clicking on the button adds the event handler that has the problem. Anyway, I'll bet your code has the same problem of firing multiple events.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/yaFeF/26/. This is your code, and it has the same problem when you press Enter.